# Why does Blend need to change a project created in VS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, visual-studio-2017, blend

[I asked this question in MSDN in June and have had no replies as yet so I am hoping that I can get an answer here. A stackoverflow search for "uwp blend" yielded exactly 100 results, none of which are for the same issue as here.]

I created a brand new WIndows Template Studio solution - called "AppName" - with VS 15.7.3 and added a .NET Standard 2.0 class library project - called "ConversionService" - to the solution.
When I tried to open the solution in VS Blend 15.7.3 (same version number as VS) I got the following - rather scary - message:

---

One-way upgrade
Visual Studio will automatically make functional changes to the following projects in order to open them. You will not be able to open these projects in the version of Visual Studio in which they were originally created.
     - ConversionService, "[location redacted]ConversionService.csproj"

Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - AppName, "[location redacted]\AppName.sln"

No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - , ""

---

What does the above message mean? (I redacted the actual file locations.)
It seems to say that I won't be able to go back into VS to edit the ConversionService project, which is definitely something I want to be able to do.
Why does VS Blend 15.7.3 seemingly not like projects created in VS 15.7.3?

(I previously had the same issue with another completely separate solution containing UWP and NET Standard projects but I didn't need Blend for that.)

Comment: If you're using some form of version control (you should), why not let it perform the upgrade? At worst, if it turns out you were right that you'd no longer be able to open in VS, it's a simple rollback. And you can diff the before/after to see *what it actually changed*. These are things you should have been able to do whilst waiting (unsuccessfully) for an answer on MSDN.

Comment: I could try to reproduce the issue but I'm on 15.7.5 and I'm not sure what a "Windows Template Studio solution" means so can't be sure I'm following those same steps. If you make clear what steps you've followed, I should at least be able to tell you whether an upgrade might clear the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Luckily, I've not needed Blend on the project so far - so it's not been a big issue yet - but it's something that will be needed soon. To make things more simple I tried this: With VS 15.7.**5** I created a new basic no-frills UWP Blank App solution. Within that solution I created a .NET Standard class library. No changes to either, just what VS created. App runs as expected, no errors. With Blend 15.7.5 I tried to open the solution and got the same message as above (but with different filenames).

Comment: I let Blend make its changes to this disposable solution and it looks okay and I can edit it in VS just fine but, as it's got no functionality, I can't tell if anything major has happened. I'll give it a try on my real project - as you suggest - and see what happens. As you say, I can always back the changes out. (It's still a scary message though.)

Comment: I took the plunge and let Blend convert the solution. Blend added ToolsVersion="15.0", a <FileUpgradeFlags>, an <UpgradeBackupLocation>, and an <OldToolsVersion> - which was set to 2.0 for some reason - to the csproj of two projects. (It also complained that two unit test projects were incompatible but that's not a problem.) All looks okay so far and I seem to be able to go back and forth between VS and Blend just fine (fingers crossed).

Comment: The unit test projects marked by Blend as incompatible - which is fine as Blend isn't for that sort of thing - also showed as incompatible in VS.
However, all you need to do is right-click each 'incompatible' project and re-load it to get it back.
Not a perfect solution but it seems to work.